# How to do screen sharing in agora without getting an authentication problem

Tags: vue.js, video-streaming, agora.io, screensharing

I've implemented the agora sdk 3.0 for video calls.

now I'm trying to get screen sharing to work, but I keep getting the error provided in
the picture below (Join failed: NO_AUTHORIZED).

[Picture of console while sharing a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egtzY.png)

screen sharing code sample:

```
async shareScreen() {
  this.shareClient = AgoraRTC.createClient({
    mode: 'rtc',
    codec: 'vp8'
  })

  this.shareClient.init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', () => {
    this.shareClient.join('same token video call started with', 'same room name of current outgoing video call', null, (uid) => {
      const streamSpec = {
        streamID: uid,
        audio: false,
        video: false,
        screen: true
      }
      if (isFirefox()) {
        streamSpec.mediaSource = 'window';
      } else if (!isCompatibleChrome()) {
        streamSpec.extensionId = 'minllpmhdgpndnkomcoccfekfegnlikg';
      }
      this.shareScreenStream = AgoraRTC.createStream(streamSpec);
      // Initialize the stream.
      this.shareScreenStream.init(() => {
        // Play the stream.
        this.shareScreenStream.play('renderer');
        // Publish the stream.
        this.shareClient.publish(this.shareScreenStream);

      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screensharing client should use an unique token based on the UID and channel name. Not the one the main user is using.